# Sending a video from the backend to the frontend then playing it with flask & react

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, video, blob

After sending the video from the flask app to the front-end and trying to set the blob into a playable URL from the frontend it doesn't seem to accept the blob as a video source

```
@app.route('/summarize/<video_name>', methods=['GET'])
def get_video(video_name):
    return send_file(f"custom-video/{video_name}", mimetype='video/mp4')
```

```
const playVideo = async () => {
    axios
      .get(url, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
        },
        responseType: "blob",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        setVideoUrl(videoURL);
      });
  };
```

I've tried many times to send the video file to the frontend however the blob seems to be received fine but i cannot display it in the video player
[response log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDjXb.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1VVc.png)

i tried different mime types and also setting the blob url with different ways and still it doesnt work on chrome, firefox and edge